# Best Way to Implement Unique ID DynamoDB Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an app where users can create posts that uses Amazon DynamoDB. One of the attributes of a post item in the database is `postId`. I am searching for the best practice to set this value upon creation. So far, I have thought of:

1. Counting the current items in the DB and then assigning the value as `postId = dbcount + 1`. I cannot find a count method for DynamoDB using Swift, and the ways I have found (scan & description) are either inefficient or accurate. Also, I thought of the scenario of 2 users posting at the same time.
2. I could create a UUID with Swift and set the postId to this value.

Upon these 2 options, which route is better? Is there a preferred industry standard? Option 2 seems to be the better choice, but I am not sure. Are there any other potential alternatives? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely stay away from option 1 - as you said the potential for a race condition is too high and it could be expensive to implement too.

A UUID would certain work and is likely to be the least painful.  However, there are other options too.  An [atomic counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) would work.  A bit more complicated but you could even use a [conditional write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate).  But the logic for that would be a pain.

The advantage of the UUID is that **you** generate it so that it can be used for, as an example, a row of data in a child table.